# How to find the determinant of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, conic-sections

I'd like to find the **`determinant`** of following matrix

$$
\begin{pmatrix} {x_1}^2 & x_1y_1 & {y_1}^2 & x_1 & y_1 \\ 
{x_2}^2 & x_2y_2 & {y_2}^2 & x_2 & y_2 \\ 
 {x_3}^2 & x_3y_3 & {y_3}^2 & x_3 & y_3 \\ 
 {x_4}^2 & x_4y_4 & {y_4}^2 & x_4 & y_4 \\ 
{x_5}^2 & x_5y_5 & {y_5}^2 & x_5 & y_5 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $ x_i \not=x_j $, 
$ y_i \not= y_j $ for $ i \not= j $
($ i,j=1,2,3,4,5$)

And I'd like to verify the determinant is ***not zero***.

$$
$$

I was wondering this while studying

Vandermonde matrix, conic section - five points ...  and so on.

$$
$$

By the way,

could recommend any program or website which calculate determinant of matrix?

Actually I touched "wolframalpha.com", but wolfram can't recognize my input.
(maybe I did mistake...)

$$
$$
Thank you for your attention to this matter.

$$
$$

> **EDIT** (ADD)

The conic section equation will be of the form

$$
Ax^2 + Bxy+Cy^2 +D x+Ey +F= 0 --- (*)
$$with A, B, C not all zero

If the points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), \cdots, (x_5, y_5)$ satisfy **(*)**
, then

$$
\begin{pmatrix} {x_1}^2 & x_1y_1 & {y_1}^2 & x_1 & y_1 \\ 
{x_2}^2 & x_2y_2 & {y_2}^2 & x_2 & y_2 \\ 
 {x_3}^2 & x_3y_3 & {y_3}^2 & x_3 & y_3 \\ 
 {x_4}^2 & x_4y_4 & {y_4}^2 & x_4 & y_4 \\ 
{x_5}^2 & x_5y_5 & {y_5}^2 & x_5 & y_5 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} A \\ 
B \\ C \\ D \\ E \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
-F \\ -F \\ -F \\ -F \\ -F \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
$$

BUT in this time

I know the fact(statement) "five points decide conic section UNIQUELY"

So, I thought the determinant of matrix will be ***nonzero***

(and I asked you guys that 'convinced me the determinant is nonzero'...)

BUT the determinant is **zero**...

$$
$$

**Where I did mistake?**

PLEASE help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Matlab's symbolic toolbox...](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/)

Comment: wolfram can recognize the matrix as the following {{x_1^2%2Cx_1y_1%2Cy_1^2%2Cx_1%2Cy_1}%2C{x_2^2%2Cx_2y_2%2Cy_2^2%2Cx_2%2Cy_2}%2C{x_3^2%2Cx_3y_3%2Cy_3^2%2Cx_3%2Cy_3}%2C{x_4^2%2Cx_4y_4%2Cy_4^2%2Cx_4%2Cy_4}%2C{x_5^2%2Cx_5y_5%2Cy_5^2%2Cx_5%2Cy_5}}

Comment: A $5\times 5$ determinant can be computed using any symbolic CAS. Maple, MATLAB Sym, Mathematica etc. or, quite cumbersome, using Leibniz formula.

Comment: [$\det(M)=0$ @ W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e2q1bfp8p6r)...

Comment: Determinant is non trivial iff the rank is full. Therefore i would try to show linear independence of the rows or columns.

Comment: http://bit.ly/1qi3xtj

Comment: One idea is like this: Let $P(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_5,y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_5) =\det A$. Then try to factorize $P$.

Comment: @oliveeuler The link you give isn't show 'all' RESULT.. So, I substitute the value, bit.ly/1mkGGoM ,  and I'm embarrassed :-)

Comment: I'll be back after thinking more this problem...
THANKS EVERYBODY... :-D

Comment: @user143993 I'm confused by what you mean. I thought you wanted the general solution? And in yours, you have $15$ in the place of $1\cdot5$?

Comment: I added my question, could you guys check this again please?

Comment: The determinant of the matrix is zero iff the conic that passes through the 5 points also pass through the origin. To see the determinant need not be zero, just compute the determinant for any five points on the unit circle....

Comment: @achillehui Let me think about it. Actually I don't understand the 1st sentence "~pass through the origin".. why origin? When I substitued five values (not on conic section pass through the origin), then the determinant is also zero.....

Comment: @user143993 Try calculate the determinant yourself on following 5 points on the unit circle. $(\pm 1, 0), (0,\pm 1)$ and $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$. It is $2$ not $0$.

Comment: Why the origin? The equation for the unique conic passing through 5 distinct points is given by:
$$\begin{vmatrix} 
x^2   & xy & y^2 & x & y & 1\\
x_1^2 & x_1y_1 & y_1^2 & x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\ 
x_2^2 & x_2y_2 & y_2^2 & x_2 & y_2 & 1\\ 
x_3^2 & x_3y_3 & y_3^2 & x_3 & y_3 & 1\\ 
x_4^2 & x_4y_4 & y_4^2 & x_4 & y_4 & 1\\ 
x_5^2 & x_5y_5 & y_5^2 & x_5 & y_5 & 1\\ 
\end{vmatrix} = 0$$
At the origin $(x,y) = (0,0)$, the value of LHS reduces to your determinant (up to a sign). So the origin lies on the unique conic if and only if your determinant vanish.

Comment: Try calculate the determinant yourself on following 5 points on the unit circle. (±1,0),(0,±1) and (12√,12√). It is 2 not 0 ////////////// I agree this one

Comment: Why the origin? The equation for the unique conic passing through 5 distinct points is given by: //////////////// BUT I curious about that... (sorry if you feel I offend you, but I'm not, I really wonder about)

Comment: Of course, for x=0=y , determinant is zero!! /// BUT HOW can say  the determinant is not zero for any x, y (are not all zero)

Answer (score 2):

For $x_i = y_i$ this is pretty wrong. Determinant is zero iff rank is not full. But if $(x_1,\cdots,x_5)=(y_1,\cdots,y_5)$ this is already wrong.

Comment: no it's not. only $x_i \neq x_j$

Comment: sorry, I'd misread it

Comment: I also realized it at second view.

Answer (score 1):

If the determinant is zero then the columns are related, which means there exist $a,b,c,d,e$ such that 
$$ ax_i^2 + bx_iy_i+cy_i^2 +d x_i+ey_i = 0,\ i=1..5.$$
Then $P_i(x_i,y_i)$ are on the same conic.

Therefore the determinant can be zero, and is zero if and only if the points $P_i$ lie on the same conic in the plane.

Comment: Is $ax_i^2 + bx_iy_i+cy_i^2 +d x_i+ey_i +f= 0$ right, ins't it?

Comment: No, there is no $f$ here. The equation still defines a conic.

Comment: I'd like to check this, [the columns are related] if and only if [the column vectors are independendent]

Comment: @user143993: The statement you wrote is not right. The determinant is zero if and only if the columns (or the lines) are related. You can prove it like this: if the determinant is not zero, then any relation between the columns implies that the coefficients are zero (because the system has the unique solution of zeros). Therefore the columns are not related. Conversely, if the determinant is zero, then the system doesn't have a unique solution, i.e. has a non zero solution, i.e. you can find a relation between the column vectors.

Comment: Ummm, Is $ax_i^2 + bx_iy_i+cy_i^2 +d x_i+ey_i +f= 0$ general conic section equation ??

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake..
I'd like to check this, [the columns are related] if and only if [the column vectors are **dependendent**]

Comment: @user143993: This last equivalence you wrote is the definition of dependent vectors.

Comment: Given any 5 generic points in the plane, there is always a conic passing through them. What you have is the conic that passes through these $5$ point has $f = 0$. This is equivalent to that conic passing through the origin.

Comment: I added my question, could you guys check this again please?